# Are non-blocking UDP sockets completely redundant?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

How are non-blocking UDP sockets **not** completely pointless?

I see no advantage of using them over blocking UDP sockets, and don't understand why they exist as a construct. Books don't address this. What am I missing?

#### Contextualizing my understanding

I understand the advantages of non-blocking TCP sockets to write scalable servers. As a TCP socket (blocking or non-blocking) represents a connection to a **single** remote host, it can only send and receive data from that host. So if you have 1 thread serving more than 1 connection, i.e. more than 1 socket instance per thread, than if one of them blocks, the remaining won't get served. So you need a model of 1 thread per connection (i.e. socket instance), but this doesn't scale well because each thread comes at a cost (famous C10k problem).

Non-blocking solves the issue by having 1 thread serving many TCP connections. In Java parlance, a Selector is able to tell when **at least** one Channel is ready for IO and tell which Channels are ready. A Selector in non-blocking IO is a multiplexer across many TCP sockets.

Now, in UDP, a `DatagramSocket` already acts as a multiplexer.
A single (blocking) UDP socket can receive (and send) datagrams from any remote host, so when I do

```scala
import java.net.{DatagramPacket, DatagramSocket}

val udpSocket = new DatagramSocket(<some-port>)
def run(): Unit = {
  val packet = new Datagrampacket(new Array[Byte](150), 150)
  udpSocket.receive(packet)
  // datagram contains the source IP and port.
  // do something with the datagram
  run()
}
```

The blocking `receive` will return when I receive data from **ANY** remote UDP socket. So the behavior that is only achievable with non-blocking channels/selectors in TCP, can be achieved by blocking UDP due to the nature of UDP.

Does this make sense?

1. If so, why do we also have the concept of non-blocking UDP connections in Java? What value do they add?
2. I imagine the underlying OS also has that construct? Why?

Answer (score 2):

> The blocking receive will return when I receive data from ANY remote UDP socket.

An unbound UDP socket will receive data from any remote UDP socket - as long as it is destined for the specific IP and port the local socket is bound to. So, if you want to have multiple UDP endpoints with different ports in your application, you need to create multiple sockets for this. A common use case for this are real-time audio and video in SIP, H.323, WebRTC ... where each media channel is typically using a different port.

Apart from that it can also be useful to actually bind UDP sockets so that one socket receives data only from a specific remote endpoint. This can make programming easier but also can help with scaling the application by removing the single socket bottleneck.